# Create multicolor arc using css

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create something similar to the image below using CSS. I've tried a few different options including the code below with no success. What am I missing? Any suggestions? [image]

```css
.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  -webkit-mask-image: radial-gradient(65% 50% at top, transparent 80%, #fff 81%);
  
  mask-image: radial-gradient(65% 50% at top, transparent 80%, #fff 81%);
  
  background:linear-gradient(90deg, #FFC80B 50%, #FFC80B 51%, #13ADA8 51%);
}
```

```html
<div class="container"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use multiple `radial-gradient`

```css
.container {
  height: 200px;
  background:
   /*               size    at position, colors*/
   radial-gradient(90%  80% at 50%  0  ,#0000 99%,blue),
   radial-gradient(115% 90% at 0    0  ,#0000 99%,#13ADA8),
   radial-gradient(115% 90% at 100% 0  ,#0000 99%,#FFC80B);
}
```

```html
<div class="container"></div>
```